# Fancybox alt tag loop

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-3

I'm using Fancybox 3 and I need to insert an alt tag into the rendered pop up image tag (this one:)

```
<div class="fancybox-placeholder" style="transform: translate3d(311px, 44px, 0px); width: 454px; height: 318px; opacity: 1; transition: none 0s ease 0s ;">
    <img class="fancybox-image" src="pathtoimage/image.png" alt="This needs an alt tag but right now doesn't have one">
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

This is my markup, looped in Jekyll:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="{{ project.name }}" href="{{ path to image }}.png" data-caption="{{ site.blurb }}" title="{{ data[1] }}">
    <img src="{{ path to thumbnail }}.png" alt="{{ data[1] }}" />
</a>
```

`{{ data[1] }}` is where I've defined the alt tag. The thumbnail alt tag seems to override the title in the `a` tag. Is there a way to get it so that when the main image is popped up, there is an alt tag (or title tag) associated with it?

I tried this but it's not working for some reason:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  image : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
});
```

Comment: Why would you expect that your last code snippet would work? There is no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this, add a data attribute to the a tag

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="{{ project.name }}" href="{{ path to image }}.png" data-caption="{{ site.blurb }}" title="{{ data[1] }}" data-alt="{{data[1]}}">
    <img src="{{ path to thumbnail }}.png" alt="{{ data[1] }}" />
</a>
```

and then here

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function (instance, slide) {
     $(".fancybox-image").attr("alt", slide.opts.$orig.data('alt'));
  }
});
```

here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/xploshioOn/pen/RVRBZM?editors=1010) for the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The rendered pop up image still has no alt tag. Any idea why it's not working? I added data-alt="test" to the a tag.

Answer (score -1):

Solution by "xploshioOn" would not work as expected, because `afterLoad` event is called for each gallery item. Therefore - the last loaded image would set the same `alt` value for each gallery image.

Here is an updated code:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function (instance, slide) {
     slide.$slide.find('img').attr("alt", slide.opts.$orig.data('alt'));
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdEPRZ?editors=1010

Edit: I`m surprised about downvote - as the author of the fancyBox, how can I not give correct answer? Just trust me :)

Comment: As you see on the working example of the answer, the solution is working as expected, any of the images have the alt that was added in the data attribute for the respective image. can you reproduce the error that you are mentioning with my code? thanks.

Comment: There is no need to reproduce (although, you can clearly see that in your codepen demo), because the code logic works as I described - if gallery contains more than one image, it loads current and next/previous ones. Therefore your callbacks would execute 3 times, and each time would set different alt attribute to all images currently inside fancybox.

Comment: cool @janis, didn't understand your comment before, now I know what is happening, thanks.